# Column isn't responsive

Tags: views, theming

[image: this is what I want]

[image: this is what I'm getting]

I have inserted a view and one column refuses to word wrap on mobile display. On normal desktop display it wraps just fine. But as seen in the second image taken on my phone, it puts everything in that one column only as one sentence.

This only happens with this view table. A regular table works fine as seen in the second image.

So, how do I fix this? Most using my site uses it via phone, and this is breaking their experience. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the same effect using for example the chrome developer tools, where you can set the screen dimensions.

In you specific case, you have a `white-space: nowrap` applied to your table cells for devices up to 768px. This is what prevents the line wrapping, see these screenshots.

What your site currently has:

[image: screenshot of chrome devtools with the original attributes]

With the `white-space: nowrap` removed:

[image: screenshot of chrome devtools with change to white-space attribute]

Comment: I appreciate your help! Now, to try and find this tables.less file. Just going to the listed location was a bust.... Still looking though.

Comment: Ok I was able to fix this. I added the following to my stylesheet...

.table-responsive>.table>tbody>tr>td, .table-responsive>.table>tbody>tr>th, .table-responsive>.table>tfoot>tr>td, .table-responsive>.table>tfoot>tr>th, .table-responsive>.table>thead>tr>td, .table-responsive>.table>thead>tr>th {
    white-space: normal !important;}